# Get the desired horizontal margin independently on how the items are in the html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply a CSS rule that fits the next scenarios independently on the layout inside the button.
scenario 1: text
scenario 2: text + icon
scenario 3: icon + text

This is the desired behavior:

[image]

For now, I am applying padding to the button, so it works for scenario 1 and then I tried to add a margin to the icon image. However, it is added to the padding and its side becomes bigger than the other.

You can see the issue in the following image.

[image]

Can this be achieved with the only CSS?

code

```html
<button class="pzl-button pzl-button-base primary">BUTTON</button>
<button class="pzl-icon-button pzl-button-base primary">BUTTON<img class="pzl-icon-button" src="assets/icon/chevron.svg"></button>
<button class="pzl-icon-button pzl-button-base primary"><img class="pzl-icon-button" src="assets/icon/chevron.svg">BUTTON</button>
```

css

```css
.pzl-button-base {
    margin: 8px;
    background: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3.5px 16px;
    font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.pzl-button-base.primary{
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    background: #E9B56F;
    color: #FAFAFA;
}

.pzl-button-base.primary img {
    filter: invert(99%) sepia(35%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(173deg) brightness(113%) contrast(96%);
    height: 1.5em;
}

.button-chevron-inverted {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}

.pzl-button-base img {
    padding: 0 6px;
}
```

Comment: I don’t see _where_ you are adding any margin on the image in your code, and I don’t get from your description _why_ you want to do it in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe In my example, I am using padding instead of margin, in this case, both acts equally. The problem is: if I add margin/padding on both sides (left and right) the padding of the button is added to the padding of the image and then we have more space on one side than the other. My question is about how to detect if the layout has the image on the right or on the left to apply the margin/padding to the opposite side. or maybe combine the margins as it happens when the margins get overlapped vertically.

Comment: CSS can not really “detect” that, not with this markup. If you wrapped the button _text_ into an additional span - then you could format the image differently, based on whether it is a following sibling of a span. But if you can already add the image before or after the text - then it should not be too big of a problem, to add an additional class on the button element itself at the same time, and then use that in a selector that formats the image differently. This sounds like you are putting way too much emphasis on a “pure” solution here, rather than going with something simple & practical.

Comment: Plus, your two img elements in the given example are already different to begin with - one has the class `pzl-icon-button`, the other doesn’t. So why don’t you simply use that class to apply a different margin as well then?

Comment: @CBroe I see, my intention was to create my own component library, and I would like to achieve that with the minimum classes, so it makes it easier to use the library.

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS box model, which might help you to visualise the issue you are having:

[image]

Any margin you add to the icon image will come on the 'outside' of the padding property.

I am not 100%  sure what you are asking, but if you are trying to add a margin between each of the 3 buttons, then you need to apply the margin property to the buttons, not to the icon images.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but doesn't fit the problem, the problem is about keeping the layout not adding a margin to the button

Answer (score 0):

does this helps ?

```css
.textbox {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
width: 8rem;
height: 2rem;
border: 2px solid orange;
margin-left:1rem;
background:orange;
}

.text {
position:relative;
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
color:white;
margin-top:7px;
}

.leftarrow {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
float:right;
margin-right:1rem;
}
.rightarrow {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
margin-left:1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="textbox"><div class="text">BUTTON</div></div>
<div class="textbox"><div class="text"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right leftarrow"></i>BUTTON</div></div>
<div class="textbox"><div class="text"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left rightarrow"></i>BUTTON</div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't want to add a class to the icons, I just want to keep the same margins for Icon + text inside the button vs text + icon, as the first image, but without hardcoding the position of the items, just playing with the natural box flow, playing with the margins.